# Как правильно организовать проверку ключа подписки на приложение без доступа в сеть?

Tags: методы, защита

Когда приложение просит ввести ключ активации подписки, то проверка идет запросом на правильность ключа к владельцу. В моем случае, есть вариант того, что доступа в интернет может не быть. Я понял, что нужно будет сделать обфускацию кода для затруднения понимания работы приложения. Если буду сравнивать совпадение ключа, либо метод, каким был создан ключ, то это не защитит приложение от копирования. Что поможет мне решить эту проблему?

Comment: Ничего не поможет, захотят — взломают. Можно лишь пытаться делать что-нибудь, чтобы не захотели

Comment: Да и требование доступа в интернет тоже могут выковырять, если захотят

Comment: Понял, но тогда, какие варианты помимо всего есть для "отбития" желания? на всякий случай, чтобы тоже понимал.